# probability showing incorrectly when copying to another field

Tags: custom-field

I have setup a simple process builder flow that copies the opportunity probability to another object.  The field data type is the same `percent(3,0)`. However, if the probability is 75% on the opportunity, it displays as 1% on the new object record, but if I edit, it shows up as 0.75? How can I get this to show up consistent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're probably accidentally losing a few decimal places during the conversion, and the UI is just rounding up .75 to 1. Meaning you have 75% on the Opportunity (.75), and this exact value is being copied to a percent field, so on the new object, Salesforce thinks you mean .75%, and it rounds it up to 1% on the UI.

Just multiply the value on Opportunity by 100 if you want them to mirror.